# How to implement IsEnabledChanged of silverlight dataform using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am looking for an example of how to implement the property IsEnabledChanged of the dataform using MVVM light, I set up the triggers but not sure about the implementation. So, here is the code behind version:

```
  void DataForm_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(DataForm, "Disabled", true);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(DataForm, "Normal", true);
        }
    }

DataForm.IsEnabledChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(DataForm_IsEnabledChanged);
```

in xaml using MVVM light I did this:

```
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsEnabledChanged">
                    <cmdextras:EventToCommand Command="{Binding IsEnabledChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
```

Now, need to figure out how to translate the code behind to use the relaycommand.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: What is wrong with your code-behind? if it works - why change it? The code you are executing is tightly coupled to your view. There is not need to involve the view-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Behavior that does something similar with EditStarted event of a data form.

```
public class EditableDataFormBehavior : Behavior<RadDataForm>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.CurrentItemChanged += AssociatedObject_CurrentItemChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var editableObject = AssociatedObject.CurrentItem as INotifyEditableObject;
        if (editableObject != null)
        {
            editableObject.EditStarted += Object_EditStarted;
        }
    }

    void Object_EditStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.BeginEdit();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        // detach the event handler
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        AssociatedObject.CurrentItemChanged -= AssociatedObject_CurrentItemChanged;

        var editableObject = AssociatedObject.DataContext as INotifyEditableObject;
        if(editableObject!=null)
            editableObject.EditStarted -= Object_EditStarted;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }


}
```

You would just need to modify slightly by attaching to the IsEnabledChanged event instead. You are trying to achieve a view only behavior and the viewmodel should know nothing about it. Main benefit doing it this way is that it is more reusable than code behind.

In the event handler you would add your code:

```
    if (!IsEnabled)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(DataForm, "Disabled", true);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(DataForm, "Normal", true);
    }
```

Attach the behavior to the data form (mine was made for telerik's one but should be doable with the sdk)

```
 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <utilities:EditableDataFormBehavior/>
 </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Hi, i am goona give this behavior a shot and let you know how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`EventTrigger` only deals with [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx) ([see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx#memberList1)). As you dealing with a [dependency property changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertychangedeventhandler.aspx) the `EventTrigger` simply does not recognize it.

So from what I can see using code behind is the only way of achieving the functionality you require. Also you are dealing with a functionality that belongs to the view and is bound to the control you are using (the `DataForm` in this case). Therefore, it would be contra-productive to pull that dependency into the view model, as the view model should be independent form any given implementation of the view - i.e. the goal is to design your view model so that it can be used independent from the view and the controls uesed therein.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll first try the behavior that SalieHendrix provided.