# Does caliburn micro support IsEnabledChanged?

Tags: wpf, action, caliburn.micro

I want to have a method fire when a button's enabled state changes, but it does not work. The method void EnableStartScan(bool isEnabled) in the view model never gets called.

```
<telerik:RadRibbonGroup Header="{x:Static res:StringTable.MachineCtrl}">
    <telerik:RadRibbonButton x:Name="btnStart" 
                             Text="{x:Static res:StringTable.Start}" 
                             Size="Large"
                             LargeImage="/MCSP;component/Resources/Images/Button-Start.png">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsEnabledChanged">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="EnableStartScan">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=btnStart, Path=IsEnabled}"/>
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </telerik:RadRibbonButton>
</<telerik:RadRibbonGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wy not control the state of your button in your ViewModel in the first place? Simply add a gate method in your viewModel and add trigger your other action within your viewModel

```
public bool CanSayHello(string name)
{
    if(EvalIfEnable())
    {
        YourOtherMethod();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void SayHello(string name)
{
    ExecuteYourAction();
}
```

Comment: This was what i did. I was just trying to have the gate method to only return true/false without calling YourOtherMethod(). I saw an entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937185/how-to-implement-isenabledchanged-of-silverlight-dataform-using-mvvm which state that EventTrigger only deals with routed events and doesn't recognize dependency property changed event.