# EventTrigger fails to trigger on IsEnabledChanged

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I have a custom control inherited from `UserControl` that I am enabling/disabling via a binding and trying to use an `EventTrigger` for `IsEnabledChanged` to cause a `ChangePropertyAction` behavior to execute.

```
            <local:StockmarketFilecard x:Name="StockmarketReport2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="0" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.BankReportEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                <Interactions:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Interactions:EventTrigger EventName="IsEnabledChanged">

                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="MaxHeight"  Value="100"/>
                    </Interactions:EventTrigger>
                </Interactions:Interaction.Triggers>
            </local:StockmarketFilecard>
```

`Interactions` uses the http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors namespace.

Problem is that the `ChangePropertyAction` is not executed despite the control visibly becoming enabled/disabled. I have tested adding a code-behind eventhandler for `IsEnabledChanged` on the control and it is called as expected. I have also tested triggering on the `Loaded` event to verify that the action is correct and the control changes as expected.

What am I missing to get the `EventTrigger` to trigger on `IsEnabledChanged`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing to get the `EventTrigger` to trigger on `IsEnabledChanged`?

The fact that the `EventTrigger` only handles routed events and `IsEnabledChanged` is not a routed event.

You may either set the `MaxHeight` property in an event handler in the code-behind of the view, or implement an attached behaviour as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937185/how-to-implement-isenabledchanged-of-silverlight-dataform-using-mvvm).